# Arduino Nano PID Controller with Potentiometer + IBT-2 Motor Control Board

Tags: motor, pid

I have a potentiometer connected to an analog pin A1 and would like to implement PID
Control to move a robot arm up and down based on to a given serial command. For this
to work I will need PID out produce a direction and speed output.

```
#include <AutoPID.h>

// PID settings and gains
#define OUTPUT_MIN 0
#define OUTPUT_MAX 255
#define KP 0.12
#define KI 0.8
#define KD 0.003


// Variables on PID values
float analogReadValue, setPoint, outputVal;

int SENSOR_PIN = A0; // center pin of the potentiometer

int RPWM_Output = 10; //IBT-2 Motor Control 
int LPWM_Output = 11; // 

bool BarUp;
bool BarLow;
bool BarStop;

float sensorA1;

char c;

// Input/output variables passed by reference, so they are updated automatically
AutoPID myPID(&analogReadValue, &setPoint, &outputVal, OUTPUT_MIN, OUTPUT_MAX, KP, KI, KD);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Motor Direction controls
  pinMode(RPWM_Output, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LPWM_Output, OUTPUT);

  myPID.setTimeStep(500);
}

float AnalogSensor()
{
    // read the input on analog pin 0:
    int sensorValue = analogRead(SENSOR_PIN);
    // Convert the analog reading (which goes from 0 - 1023) to a voltage (0 - 5V):
    float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);

    return voltage;
}

void loop()
{
   analogReadValue=AnalogSensor(); 

  //Reading serial command
  if(Serial.available())
  {
     char c = Serial.read();

     if(c=='r')
     {
         BarLow=false;
         BarUp=true;
         Serial.println("Arm is Rising");
     }
     else if(c=='l')
     {
         BarUp=false;
         BarLow=true;
         Serial.println("Arm is lowering");
     }
}

if(BarUp)
{
  setPoint=UpperLimit;
  myPID.run(); 
}

if(BarLow)
{
  setPoint=LowerLimit;
  myPID.run(); 
}
}


void RaiseArm()
{
   analogWrite(LPWM_Output, 0);
   analogWrite(RPWM_Output, 20);

   delay(1000);

   StopArm();

   BarUp=false;
 }


 void LowerArm()
 {
   analogWrite(LPWM_Output, 20);
   analogWrite(RPWM_Output, 0);

   delay(1000);

   StopArm();

   BarLow=false;

 }

 void StopArm()
 {
    analogWrite(LPWM_Output, 0);
    analogWrite(RPWM_Output, 0);
 }
```

Ideally I would like to set the Setpoint to analog 5.0 for raising arm and analog
0 for lower arm. Baring in mind.

```
   analogWrite(LPWM_Output, 20);
   analogWrite(RPWM_Output, 0);
```

Is for raising arm and

```
   analogWrite(LPWM_Output, 20);
   analogWrite(RPWM_Output, 0);
```

Is lowering arm. Hope you can help as the current system is not implementing PID that can
potentially work. How can I out put a direction and speed from my pid function call to control the arm.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem in doing that? You didn't describe how exactly this is not working. Please be way more specific.

Comment: How can I output a direction and speed from my pid function call to control the arm direction and speed.  As I have not worked with PID previously.

Comment: do you understand the example code that is included with the AutoPID library?

Comment: Yes I understand parts of it but learning as I go. The Setpoint would be the desired Potentiometer value. I am trying to figure out how the output can be integrated with the direction and speed values to control the motor. analogWrite(LPWM_Output, 20);
   analogWrite(RPWM_Output, 0);

Comment: The text about raising and lowering the arm doesn't match the code.  What does `analogWrite(LPWM_Output, 20)` actually do?  Is it's '20' what you would want to affect with the PID?    The way to understand PID is to focus on the "P"roportional term and the proportion of setpoint error that you want to convert into process output. Are you converting Ohms of error into PID duty cycle?  Volts of error into a servo position?  AnalogRead counts into speed?